# Retrieving data from ListView control in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, listview, highlight

I have a ListView setup in details mode that looks like this:

[image]

When the user presses the delete button, I need to go ahead and delete their record from the database. This I can do fine, but I'm stuck on how I retrieve the data that is highlighted in the ListView control. I've tried using Google but all the examples I found have failed to work.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: How do you bind (put informations) in the ListView? Manually, Dataset created with datasource,...?

Comment: I get results out of a MS Access database in a seperate subroutine, and it directly ads the results to the ListView control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the underlying object by using:

```
ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
```

Once you remove it from the database you should rebind the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim name, room, subject, date, period As String

If listviewName.SelectedItems.Count > 0 then

        '*********** transfer selected data on declare String variable ************'
        name= listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        room = listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
        subject = listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
        date= listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
        period= listviewName.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text

        '*********** delete **************'
        cmd1.Connection = MYSQLCON
        MYSQLCON.Open()
        cmd1.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE columnname = '" & name & "'"
        reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
        MYSQLCON.Close()

End If
```